# Weird behaviour in Task.start Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, task, distributed-computing, distributed

I am trying to write a Gossip Simulator in Elixir using GenServer. I have a main() method which acts as a client creating a network topology and starts all the actors (GenServer's). It then sends a `Genserver.cast()` to an Actor to initiate the gossip. The Actor in its `handle_cast()` starts a `Task.start()` to start gossiping with other actors. Looks like I am not using `Task.start()` (line 16 in actor.ex) in the right way as the called task `startGossiping()` is never executed nor the statements after `Task.start()`. Mix just exits without giving any error. The shortened program is given below.

actor.ex -

```
defmodule Actor do    
    use GenServer

    def init([nodeId, neighborList, algorithm]) do
        inspect "#{nodeId}"
        recCount = 1
        gossipingTask = 0
        {:ok, {nodeId, neighborList, algorithm, recCount, gossipingTask}}#nodeId, neighborList, algorithm, receivedCount
    end

    def handle_cast({:message, rumour}, state) do
        {nodeId, neighborList, algorithm, recCount, gossipingTask} = state
        IO.puts "nodeId - #{nodeId} recCount - #{recCount} handle_cast: #{rumour} gossipingTask - #{gossipingTask}"
        nL = elem(state, 1)
        IO.puts "here #{rumour}"
        gossipingTask = Task.start(fn -> startGossiping(nL, rumour) end) 
        IO.puts "Now again - #{rumour}"
        {:noreply, {nodeId, neighborList, algorithm, recCount + 1, gossipingTask}}
    end

    def startGossiping(nL, rumour) do
        IO.puts "In startGossiping "
        #{Enum.random(nL)}"
        # GenServer.cast(Proj2.intToAtom(Enum.random(nL)), {:message, rumour})
    end
end
```

proj2.ex -

```
defmodule Proj2 do
# Instructions to run the project
# 1) $mix escript.build
# 2) $escript proj2 100 full gossip

    def main(args) do
        # Receive total number of nodes, topology, algorithm, triggerNodes(optional), threshold(optional) from user.
        # Read README.md for more details
        numOfNodes = String.to_integer(Enum.at(args, 0))
        topology = Enum.at(args, 1)
        algorithm = Enum.at(args, 2)
        numOfNodes = if String.contains?(topology, "2d"), do: round(:math.pow(round(:math.sqrt(numOfNodes)), 2)), else: numOfNodes

        case topology do
            "full"          ->
                Enum.each 1..numOfNodes, fn nodeId ->
                    neighborList = getNeighborsFull(nodeId, numOfNodes)
                    inspect neighborList
                    nodeId_atom = intToAtom(nodeId)
                    GenServer.start_link(Actor, [nodeId, neighborList, algorithm], name: nodeId_atom)
                    # IO.puts "In main, nodeId = #{nodeId}"
                end
        end
        GenServer.cast(intToAtom(2), {:message, "This is Elixir Gossip Simulator"})

    end

    def getNeighborsFull(nodeId,numOfNodes) do
        range = 1..numOfNodes
        range
        |> Enum.filter(fn(value) -> value != nodeId end)
        |> Enum.map(fn(filtered_value) -> filtered_value * 1 end)
        # IO.inspect Neighboringlist
    end

    def intToAtom(integer) do
        integer |> Integer.to_string() |> String.to_atom()
    end
end
```

UPDATE :
Haven't figured out the problem still. I am not able to start any concurrent process actually. `spawn`, `start_link`, `Task` none of them are starting an asynchronous task.

Comment: How are you trying to run this?

Comment: 1) $ `mix escript.build` 2) $ `escript proj2 2 full gossip` . Output - nodeId - 2 recCount - 1 handle_cast: This is Elixir Gossip Simulator gossipingTask - 0 here This is Elixir Gossip Simulator $

Answer (score 0):

Neither `GenServer.cast/3` nor [`Task.start/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html#start/1) would prevent your application from exiting.

I am unsure why would you build an `escript` to test the code. You have the following options to wait until the execution finishes before exiting (including but not limited to):

• use [`mix run --no-halt`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html#content)

• create an [`Application`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Application.html)

• start the task linked and use [`Task.await/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Task.html#await/2) somewhere in your code to wait while the task is finished.

Comment: I tried running the codes separately in iex shell as - 1) $`c("proj2.ex")` 2) $`c("actor.ex")` 3) $`Proj2.main` (Hard coded the arguments) and it seems to be working fine! It is executing the task. The problem seems to be something with the way I am running the programs. I am not sure how to use $mix run as it requires a .exs file. Will update asap.